# Issues in creating/retrieving Database in Notion API

Tags: postman, notion-api

Issues in creating/retrieving Database in Notion API.

I'm trying to Notion API for getting a Database ID for using into Stack AI.

The issue when I get my databases the response is totally empty same as pages, but overall the API auth work fine because I can call all users.

This is an API request for retrieve from a database:
https://www.notion.so/8b98602edb594430bf5b7ded36e30078?v=1e840ea228274c6d8c84f085b527a6b3

I use the database id from this link `1e840ea228274c6d8c84f085b527a6b3` **So am I doing something wrong?**

[image: POSTMAN]

It always responds:

```json
{
    "object": "error",
    "status": 404,
    "code": "object_not_found",
    "message": "Could not find database with ID: 1e840ea2-2827-4c6d-8c84-f085b527a6b3. Make sure the relevant pages and databases are shared with your integration.",
    "developer_survey": "https://notionup.typeform.com/to/bllBsoI4?utm_source=postman"
}
```

When I create a new database it says:

> Error in a Page ID

however I think I do not have to provide a page id in this call.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have shared the database with your integration:

In order to do this you have to open the database in notion, click the `...` in the top right corner, and add your integration from the `Add Connections` menu.

here are some more details: https://developers.notion.com/docs/create-a-notion-integration#step-2-share-a-database-with-your-integration

The error you get when creating a database is similar, but it is now asking you to provide a page parent to the database.
Refer to the documentation for a request example: https://developers.notion.com/reference/create-a-database